# Implementing Auto-Filtering in Ext JS 7.6 Modern Form with Multiple Select Boxes

Tags: filter, extjs, drop-down-menu, frontend, tagfield

I'm working on an **Ext JS 7.6 Modern **form that contains three select boxes, each populated with users of different profiles from distinct stores. However, these select boxes can become quite lengthy, making it challenging to locate specific users manually.

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement an auto-filtering feature where I can type into an input field, and the select box would dynamically filter and display matching results as I type. This will greatly enhance the usability of my form.

Any suggestions or code examples for achieving this functionality in Ext JS 7.6 Modern would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

I tried using the tagfield but it did not work for me.

Comment: Did you check combobox of modern tookit?                                                         
Combobox example : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3jkc                                  Reference :  docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.field.ComboBox.html